# What is the proper configuration for max open connection, max idle connection and max connection life postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, configuration, aws-aurora

We have an app that serves small to moderate kinds of traffic.

our server spec:

- 6 node of micro/small aws ec2 for client
- 1 db.r5.2xlarge for writer
- 1 db.r5.large for reader

our app/client setting:

```
db.SetMaxOpenConnections(25)
db.SetMaxIdleConnections(10)
db.SetConnMaxLifetime(5 * time.Second)
```

so the question is:

1. is this app setting good enough to handle sudden high traffic?
2. yesterday we have(370k active connection), and the DB wasn't able to withstand the traffic, the CPU is increasing rapidly and we have to spin another read cluster to able to handle the traffic. but, the funny thing is, if I look into DB connection count it only has 133 max, while the capacity for DB.r5.large is 1600 connection([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Managing.html). so why can't handle the traffic with such a low connection to DB??
3. there is a strange event during this traffic, 'Read replica has fallen behind the master too much. Restarting Postgres.' is this because we had different specs between writer and reader?

Answer (score 1):

Is the pool going to the reader or the writer, or if both how does it decide?

Just because it allows you to set max_connections to 1600, doesn't mean that that is a remotely reasonable setting to use.  It doesn't have 1600 CPU cores, nor 1600 independent channels for IO.

Having the reader be substantially smaller than the writer, both in CPU and in RAM, could certainly be a reason for it to fall behind.  But so could having 133 reading processes competing for it's one CPU with the replication process.

Comment: the pool is going for both, each has a similar setting.